# Why single phase motors uses double pole single throw switches instead of a single pole single throw switch?

Tags: motor, switches, relay, electrical

I've seen many motor starters that have double poles to contact the motor leads to the AC source. I wonder if there is any reason for not using single pole single throw switches which are mostly used in all home electrical applicances.
Why the neutral wie is not directly connected to the motor?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably to avoid kickback in the neutral wire

Comment: Can you elaborate "kickback"? Is it because of the magnetic field collapse or anything else?

Comment: Think that if you just have a simple inductor just and cut of the line on one side, the inductor will try to force a current while it's still charged until it no more can.

Same with the engine